# Caps lock delay problem

Tags: keyboard

With using caps lock for word capitalization, when I type *fast* using my Linux distro, I get the following:

```
CAps LOck NOt WOrking PRoperly.
```

I tried the same keyboard on a windows machine, it works properly. So, the main reason of the problem seems to be my Linux distro.

PS1: Same problem is also mentioned here: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1462333
PS2: I use Ubuntu 13.04
PS3: Please do not give the advice to use shift instead of caps lock for capitalization purposes.

Comment: And have you tried the solution given in the thread? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1462333&page=3&p=12328951#post12328951

The bug status is "RESOLVED/FIXED":  https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27903.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the bug, even though I've never noticed it before. I'm using a Gentoo with xkeybord-config v2.7.

Comment: @lgeorget, It really worked. I was so angry to Ubuntu and apparently didn't read all the thread at the time I posted the question. Thanks.

Comment: If someone wants to properly answer the question, it may be of some help to others. I could do it, but I don't really understand the xkbcomp syntax, nor what the patch does exactly. Some explanations would be useful.

Comment: @lgeorget, If you choose answering it; I would happily mark as the answer. Thanks.